# How to prevent NavigationDrawer from being opened by gesture, but allow from hamburger icon in Support Design Library 23.1.1.1

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, navigation-drawer

I have a ViewPager where pages contain charting views which react to sliding movements. Due to this i resorted to changing the page by sliding from the edge of the screen. But that leaves me with the problem that this is also the gesture to open the NavigationDrawer.

Until now i used the following code to achieve this:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

  SetContentView(GetLayoutId());

  Toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
  if (Toolbar != null)
  {
    // set this flag so the colors colorPrimaryDark and android:statusBarColor have an effect
    // setting android:statusBarColor to transparent causes the drawer to be dran underneath a translucent status bar
    Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);

    // make the toolbar the replacement of the action bar
    SetSupportActionBar(Toolbar);
  }

  // add the hamburger icon
  m_DrawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
  var actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, m_DrawerLayout, Toolbar, Resource.String.empty, Resource.String.empty);
  m_DrawerLayout.AddDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

  // make sure the drawer can't be opened by swiping, to do this we set the lock mode to closed
  // but if we just do this, it can't be closed by swiping either, so set the lock mode to unlocked when the drawer is opened, and locked again when it's closed
  m_DrawerLayout.DrawerOpened += (object sender, DrawerLayout.DrawerOpenedEventArgs e) =>
  {
    m_DrawerLayout.SetDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LockModeUnlocked);
  };
  m_DrawerLayout.DrawerClosed += (object sender, DrawerLayout.DrawerClosedEventArgs e) =>
  {
    m_DrawerLayout.SetDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LockModeLockedClosed);
  };
  m_DrawerLayout.SetDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LockModeLockedClosed);

  //calling sync state is necessay or else the hamburger icon wont show up
  actionBarDrawerToggle.SyncState();
}
```

It worked as intended, until i updated to the Android Support Design Library 23.1.1.1, now setting the lock mode to closed also prevents the menu from being opened by tapping on the hamburger icon.

Comment: A non-standard behavior :)

Comment: May be you have to create a custom `View` extending from `DrawerLayout`.

Comment: If it is indeed the update that's causing that, it sounds like a goof on their part. You'll probably wanna revert to the previous library version until they either fix it, or state that that is now the intended behavior, which would not be fun, 'cause that would take a needlessly complicated workaround to get the old behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source code for the latest version of the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` class, this does indeed seem to be the new intended behavior. It's `toggle()` method now looks like this:

```
private void toggle() {
    int drawerLockMode = mDrawerLayout.getDrawerLockMode(GravityCompat.START);
    if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerVisible(GravityCompat.START)
        && (drawerLockMode != DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN)) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    else if (drawerLockMode != DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED) {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
}
```

whereas it previously just checked the drawer's opened/closed state.

This is unfortunate, since it will now take a workaround to achieve the old behavior. Perhaps the simplest thing to do is just to revert to an older version of the support library. However, if you want to keep the newest version, one possible solution is as follows.

First remove the `Toolbar` argument from the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` constructor call.

```
actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, 
                                                  m_DrawerLayout, 
                                                  Resource.String.empty,
                                                  Resource.String.empty);
```

This will cause the `Activity`'s `OnOptionsItemSelected()` method to fire upon clicking the toggle, since you've set the `Toolbar` as the support `ActionBar`. We will also need to call `SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` to actually show the toggle, since the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` class interacts somewhat differently with an `ActionBar` than it does with a `Toolbar`, with respect to their child `View`s.

In the `Activity`'s `OnOptionsItemSelected()` method, we then simply unlock the drawer before calling the toggle's own `OnOptionsItemSelected()` method, which handles the opening and closing of the drawer.

```
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected (IMenuItem item)
{       
    switch (item.ItemId)
    {
        case Android.Resource.Id.Home:
            m_DrawerLayout.SetDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LockModeUnlocked);
            actionBarDrawerToggle.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);

            return true;
        ...
    }
    ... 
}
```

Your `actionBarDrawerToggle` will need to be a field of your `Activity`, and you can remove the `DrawerOpened` handler.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. There is just one more thing that i needed to add: `SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` otherwise the hamburger icon won't be displayed.
And i want to avoid to have to keep using an old version of the support library. The app is still in development and i don't want to be forced to use out of date stuff even before the app is released for the first time...

Comment: Ah, yeah, guess I didn't notice you didn't have that already. Cool. Glad it worked for ya. Cheers!